# Bootstrap modal fade happening, but not pop up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to write a modal that pops on submission of login credentials (eventually I want to use ajax to verify against the ldap server and pop a modal based on group membership, but not there yet).

When I open this in a browser and click the button the container fades to dark like it should, but no actual modal div appears.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PSSST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="./static/style.css">
    <script type=text/javascript src="./static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="./static/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type=text/javascript src="./static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class=body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/landing">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class=page>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row top-buffer">
            <div class="form_bg">
                <form id="loginForm">
                     <h2 class="text-center">Login Page</h2>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                        name="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control"
                                               id="password"
                        name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="align-center">

                    </div>
                    <div class="align-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-default"
                                              id="login" data-toggle="modal"
                                              data-target="#myModal">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>MODAL</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You mistyped `modal-dialog`, you are missing dash. If you correct that, it should work

Comment: :facepalm. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  `role="document`" to the `<div class="modal-dialog" >`

It should be like this

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PSSST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>


<body class=body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="/landing">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class=page>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row top-buffer">
            <div class="form_bg">
                <form id="loginForm">
                     <h2 class="text-center">Login Page</h2>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
                        name="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control"
                                               id="password"
                        name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="align-center">

                    </div>
                    <div class="align-center">
                        <button
                        id="login"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button>


                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Product Setting</h4>
                              </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
      $('#login').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); });
</script>
```